# about the song “Another Day of Sun”

Tags: meaning, nouns

This tittle’s song was used in the famous movie “La La Land”.
Now, I have a question. What is ‘Sun’ ? 
I mean, I can’t understand what ‘Sun’ means.
Does ‘sun’ mean the sun which is a star 
or day (like every day and Sunday)?

Thank you.

Comment: Think of it as sunshine: another day of sun rather than of clouds or rain. Metaphorically, it's another day which holds out the promise of happiness.

Comment: Understand that it's metaphorical, and likely several meanings are inferred simultaneously.

Comment: @StoneyB Oh, I see! This is used as metaphor. Exactly ‘sun’ is better than others. Thank you.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you for your answer. I understand ‘sun’ has some meanings metaphorically.

Answer (score 1):

from my understanding, **Sun** in this context means " Love ", i take my example from shakespares sonnet 148. the 12th line, try googling it

```
No marvel then, though I mistake my view,
The sun itself sees not till heaven clears.
```

from the interpretation here reading from the preceeding line,

```
no marvel then though i mistake thy view
```

meaning (dont be surprised if i fall in love with the wrong person)

then he went on to say

```
the sun itself sees not till heaven clears
```

which means that **love** itself is true/sure when there is no doubt but certainty.

so the song " **Another Day of Sun** ".. means " **Another Day of LOVE** "... 
and to note.. i love that song...

Comment: It’s interesting interpretation. Thanks to your example, I understand the reason that  ‘sun’ means love. Thank you.